# Unable to get ros::params defined in bash and roslaunch to print in c++ script

Tags: c++, bash, shell, ros

I have a bash script as follows:

```bash
foldername=camera_calibration_$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
im_name="/cam0"
roslaunch image_pub cam_calibration.launch foldername:=$foldername image_name:=$im_name
```

My roslaunch script is as follows:

```xml
<launch>
  <arg name = "foldername" default="camera_calibration" />
  <arg name = "image_name" default="/cam1" />
    
  <param name="foldername" type="string" value="$(arg foldername)" />
  <param name="image_name" type="string" value="$(arg image_name)" />
  <param name="size_name" type="string" value="12x8" />
  <param name="square" type="string" value="0.05" />
    
  <node name="im_pub_sub_node" pkg="image_pub" type="im_pub_sub" output="screen"/>
  <node name="cameracalibrator_node" pkg="camera_calibration" type="cameracalibrator.py" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

My C++ script (im_pub_sub.cpp) as follows:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string foldername;
    std::string imagename;
    std::string si_name;
    ros::param::get("/size_name", si_name);
    ros::param::get("/foldername", foldername);
    ros::param::get("/image_name", imagename);
    std::cout<<imagename<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<foldername<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<si_name<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"hi"<<std::endl;
}
```

When I launch it I only get "hi" print on my console but not foldername, image_name defined from bash and si_name param defined in launch file. It prints empty like nothing for other params defined.

I can get these params printed in my python script, but I am unable to do the same using c++. This is completely "weird".

Can anyone please let me know what is wrong in my syntax?

Comment: Is this anything related to how I define my Cmake file?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. That's because you can't get rosparams from launch file until rosnode initilaization and node Nodehandler is being defined.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

ros::init(argc, argv, "im_sub_pub_cpp");
ros::NodeHandle nh_;

std::string foldername;
std::string imagename;
std::string si_name;
ros::param::get("/size_name", si_name);
ros::param::get("/foldername", foldername);
ros::param::get("/image_name", imagename);
std::cout<<imagename<<std::endl;
std::cout<<foldername<<std::endl;
std::cout<<si_name<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"hi"<<std::endl;
}
```

Then this works.